# LinkedIn not display og:image

Tags: wordpress

When I try to share an article from my WordPress website, the featured images are not displayed in LinkedIn, my open graph tags are good and the LinkedIn requirements have been respected:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Txxxxxxxxx">
    <meta property="og:description" content="xxxxxxx...">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxxxxr/">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="xxxxxxx">
    <meta property="article:published_time" content="2022-12-22T10:31:33+00:00">
    <meta property="article:modified_time" content="2022-12-22T10:51:45+00:00">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.xxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/E142CE3F-1E7D-443E-B7B0-79667773118C.jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1900">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="633">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta name="author" content="xxxxx Admin">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta name="twitter:label1" content="Written by">
    <meta name="twitter:data1" content="xxxxx Admin">
    <meta name="twitter:label2" content="Est. reading time">
    <meta name="twitter:data2" content="2 minutes">
```

LinkedIn post inspector does not help me :

[image]

I'm a little stuck on how I'm going to debug this if anyone has any ideas
Thanks

I expected that when I share my website post in Linked, image would be displayed
Thans for your helps

Comment: Did you add those tags recently or not? If so try the tool again but add a "version" to the url e.g. `https://www.example.com?v=1` - Chances are, if you added these tags recently, the parsing is still cached at LinkedIn's side

Comment: I already trick this trick bu same result

Comment: I contacted linkedin support and this was their response :

“Our Engineering Team  stated the fallowing information:
“The logs indicate that this is a site local address:
Forbidden to access link local address [www.example.com/fe80:0:0:0:102d:e3ff:fe94:168f] of url [https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/pics-11.png
] which we do not allow. This is a policy at our end to block such addresses along with loopback address and multicast addresses.”
Is this a problem with the site server configuration or something else? If it’s server side do you have any idea what I should do?